# How will a rutted farm road get worse if it is not repaired?

Tags: outdoor, driveway, soil

On a vacant lot in the northeast US, used for haying in the past, myself and a few other people started different farming projects on it. It is very wet and had an especially wet year in the past. Traffic is relatively low but we do drive pickup trucks on the field during the growing season and have had very occasional heavier trucks deliver materials.

The path we drive on is now very rutted, as expected. Road work was planned before the past growing season but was not completed. We're still trying to line up some basic road work, expecting that means installing a culvert and a gravel driveway for the worst spots. We're getting pros on it ASAP but they are busy.

My question for this community is **how is this likely to evolve if we do not do anything, or do stopgap fixes like putting small logs perpendicular to the ruts? Will it be more expensive to fix 2 or 3 years from now, versus fixing it this year?**

Here's some pictures.

This is entering the field. You're on a paved town road, then you pull off onto 20x20ft gravel driveway the town built, and that slopes down into this muddy path.
[image: front field entrance]

This is between two fields on site, over a hundred feet away from the entrance in the image above. This is a clearer case of a culvert being needed along with plenty of gravel.
[image: back field entrance]

Between the two images is about 150ft of rutted ground that stays relatively dry. We are thinking these two problem areas need 50ft or so of proper gravel driveway installed and a culvert in one or both areas. For the drier stretch we're thinking pickup trucks and the soil can tolerate it, and ideally we will at least spread 3-4 inches of woodchips every few years, to make a path that gets less degraded each use.

Comment: If you could just limit travel over the path when it is nice and dry, not much.  It is it is wet that most of the damage is done, making ruts.  Imagine you are like most people and just using it when dry is next to impossible.  Probably 2 or 3 years will not make much difference in the cost due to damage, but prices do tend to rise year over year.

Comment: I would be concerned about erosion below any gravel you put down. That soil clearly isn't draining right and a layer of gravel will help spread the weight of vehicles, but will not stop water from slowly pulling away the underlying material. If you can maintain a grass or something that will hold the soil together, that would be better than gravel

Comment: Well, the ruts get deeper, until somebody decides not to try and navigate those so tries a new tire placement, which starts a new set of ruts. Meanwhile water builds up in the ruts making them muddier and more likely to get people stuck. Then when stuck, well, you hope you have a winch and a good tree close enough...

Comment: @JonCuster does that expanding and increasingly muddy mess get more expensive to repair as it gets worse, or is it ultimately the same job for heavy machinery and materials to set it right eventually?

Comment: Blading the road and constructing appropriate crown and drainage ditches won't depend too much on ruts unless people go crazy and drive all over the place.